# Git to update all local branches according to the server side

Tags: git, github, git-branch, branching-and-merging, pull-request

So I

- pushed my **local branch** to GitHub
- created Pull request on GitHub and
- successfully merged and closed the Pull request and *watch this ...*
- ***deleted*** the branch *on GitHub site* using the “Delete Branch” button

Now, the problem is, I didn't find what/how to do next, and no matter what I did, my local branch is always there. So,

How to let git to mirror exactly what branches are there on the server, removing all branches that are no longer exist. Or, if I have to do it myself, exactly what steps I need to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the remote branch reference that is already deleted on remote.

```
$ git remote prune origin
```

Delete the local branches that is merged with the current branch

```
$ git branch --merged | grep -v '*' | xargs git branch -d
```

**Note:** If you are not on `master` then local/master can be deleted. If your want to keep `master` branch.

```
$ git branch --merged | grep -v "\*" | grep -Ev "(\*|master)" | xargs -n 1 git branch -d
```

Comment: If you can, use `git for-each-ref` rather than `git branch` in scripts. For this case (`--merged`) you need your Git version to be at least 2.7.0.

Answer (score 0):

If you want exactly the same on the remote it's better to `clone` again. But it's not a good way to do.

You can delete your local branches using

```
git branch -D BRANCH_NAME
```

If you want to get the merged branch to your local,

```
git pull origin BRANCH_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks,  "*delete local branches*", OK, but "*then fetch that branch from the remote*", hmm, why? The remote branch has been successfully deleted and no longer exist on remote server. Why this step necessary?

Comment: I thought you want to fetch that again. So edited the answer